# Can you inject a spring bean into a class not directly in spring container?

Tags: java, spring

Sorry if this question sounds vague, but I will try and add some clarity.

If I have a class association as shown below.

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

With class A being created via spring bean configuration, but B, C & D being created outside of the spring container eg directly in code.  If I want to wire a new bean into class D can I use the @Inject annotation in D and then just create an associated @Bean definition in the spring bean configuration that creates A or because B, C & D are not spring beans that will not work?

Comment: No it wont work you need to manually set that into the object D.

Comment: Ok, so to inject a spring bean into class D, I would have to have B, C & D all created as spring beans?

Comment: @PraneethRamesh you can be wrong. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html

Comment: Yeah true but that is not defaultly called by spring. You need to do it manually. If you just create any object inside D which is a non spring using new operator there is no way spring would understand that this has to be autowired. Just @Autowiring wont work. You need to call explicitly autowireBeanFactory.autowireBean(yourNewBean); so that Autowiring is processed

Comment: @PraneethRamesh OFc but if u manually create objects and want to perform injections on them... then it will be manually anyway. You dont have to explain to me how the wheel rolls

Comment: Yeah but I understand the question was not stating how to do that.. Question was will spring do it. Of course there are many ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt test that, but you may be lucky using [AutowireBeanCapableFactory#autowire](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean-java.lang.Object-) method

Bean factory can be accessed from `ApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects using `new B();` and have dependencies **managed** by `Spring` injected.

Lets say an `A` instance is managed by the `Spring` container, and `B` looks like:

```
public class B {

  @Autowire
  private A a;
...
}

...
B b = new B();
...
```

If you want to inject dependencies in `B` using `Spring`'s `@Autowire`:

- Annotate class `B` with: `@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)`
- Run the Java process using a Java agent: `java -javaagent:<path to spring-agent-${spring.version}.jar> ...`